# Radiobuttons return a value of zero regardless of selection

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I am currently working on code to solve for any variable in Ideal Gas Law and was having trouble with the output being reached.

I am eventually hoping to reach a point with this project where I have a plethora of equations and laws added to my calculator however I have started with the Ideal Gas law. I am currently having trouble with the `Tkinter` radiobuttons and retrieving the values behind selected buttons. Every time I attempt to use `.get()` my radio buttons return a value of zero regardless of selection.

I have three classes , I am currently using that will all be subdivided based upon workload. I would also really appreciate if someone could help trim the fat of my code and minimize the bulk.

GUI Class

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import math
import turtle
from turtle import*
from conversions import Conversions
from calculator import Calculator, Output
    
class CalculatorGUI:   
    """    All Branches of Calculator     """ 
        
    def IdealGasGUI():  #IDEAL GAS LAW
        master = Tk()    
        var1 = tk.IntVar()
        var2 = tk.IntVar()
        var3 = tk.IntVar()
        var4 = tk.IntVar()
        
        """    Activation Code     """
        def SolveIdeal():
            Calculate = Calculator()
            p = int(pN.get())
            v = int(vN.get())
            n = int(nN.get())
            t = int(tN.get())
                
            target = var1.get()
            pU = var2.get()
            vU = var3.get()
            tU = var4.get()
            
            Calculate.IdealGas(p,v,n,t,target,pU,vU,tU)
        
        master.geometry('540x500')
        master.title('Science Calculator © 2020 Heath Marchese All Rights Reserved')

        Label(master, text="Science Calculator - Ideal Gas Law", font='Helvetica 24 bold').grid(row=0,rowspan=2,column=0,columnspan=4,pady=(0,25),sticky=N)
        
        Label(master, text="Which variable is needed?", font ='Helvetica 14').grid(row=2,rowspan=1,column=1,columnspan=2,pady=(0,15))
    
        Radiobutton(master, text="Pressure", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var1, value=1).grid(row=3,column=0)
        Radiobutton(master, text="Volume", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var1, value=2).grid(row=3,column=1)
        Radiobutton(master, text="Mole", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var1, value=3).grid(row=3,column=2)
        Radiobutton(master, text="Temperature", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var1, value=4).grid(row=3,column=3)
        
        Label(master, text="Pressure:", font ='Helvetica 14').grid(row=4,column=0,pady=(25,5))
        pN = Entry(master)
        pN.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W,pady=(25,0)) 
        Radiobutton(master, text="kPa", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var2, value=1).grid(row=5,column=0)
        Radiobutton(master, text="torr", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var2, value=2).grid(row=5,column=1)
        Radiobutton(master, text="ATM", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var2, value=3).grid(row=5,column=2)
        Radiobutton(master, text="mmHg", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var2, value=4).grid(row=5,column=3)
        
        Label(master, text="Volume:", font ='Helvetica 14').grid(row=6,column=0,pady=(0,5))
        vN = Entry(master)
        vN.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(master, text="L", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var3, value=1).grid(row=7,column=0)
        Radiobutton(master, text="cm^3", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var3, value=2).grid(row=7,column=1)
        
        Label(master, text="Mole:", font ='Helvetica 14').grid(row=8,column=0,pady=(0,28))
        nN = Entry(master)
        nN.grid(row=8,column=1,sticky=W,pady=(0,30))
        
        Label(master, text="Temperature:", font ='Helvetica 14').grid(row=10,column=0,pady=(0,5))
        tN = Entry(master)
        tN.grid(row=10,column=1,sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(master, text="°C", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var4, value=1).grid(row=11,column=0)
        Radiobutton(master, text="°F", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var4, value=2).grid(row=11,column=1)
        Radiobutton(master, text="K", font = "Helvetica 12", variable=var4, value=3).grid(row=11,column=2)
        
        Button(master, text="Solve", font ='Helvetica 12 bold', command=SolveIdeal).grid(row=12,column=1,columnspan=2,pady=(15,0))
        Button(master, text="Return", font ='Helvetica 12 bold', command=master.quit).grid(row=13,column=1,pady=(10,0))
        Button(master, text="Quit", font ='Helvetica 12 bold', command=master.quit).grid(row=13,column=2,pady=(10,0),padx=(40))
        
            
    """    Initial Calculator Code     """ 
    master = Tk()
    Convert = Conversions()
    
    master.geometry('500x500')
    master.title('Science Calculator © 2020 Heath Marchese Some Rights Reserved')
    Button(master, text="Ideal Gas Law", font = "Helvetica 12", command=IdealGasGUI).grid()
    Button(master, text="Quit", font ='Helvetica 12 bold', command=master.quit).grid(pady=(300,0))
    
    master.mainloop()
    
start = CalculatorGUI()
```

Calculation Class

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import math
import turtle
from turtle import*
from conversions import Conversions

def Output(out):
        master = Tk()
        master.geometry('200x200')
        Label(master, text=out).grid()

class Calculator:   
    def IdealGas(master,p,v,n,t,targ,pU,vU,tU): #PV = nRT
     
        print(p)
        print(v)
        print(n)
        print(t)
        print(targ)
        print(pU)
        print(vU)
        print(tU)
        
        Convert = Conversions()
        if (pU == 1):
            p = Convert.kPa_ATM(p)
        elif (pU == 2):
            p = Convert.torr_ATM(p)
        elif (pU == 4):
            p = Convert.mmHg_ATM(p)
        if (vU == 2):
           v = Convert.cm_L(v)
        if (tU == 1):
           t = Convert.C_K(t)
        elif (tU == 2):
           t = Convert.F_K(t)
        
        if (targ == 1):
            pres = (n * 0.08205 * t) / v
            out = ("Answer: {.5f} ATM").format(pres)
            master.Output(out)
        elif (targ == 2):
            vol = (n * 0.08205 * t) / p
            out = ("Answer: {.5f} L").format(vol)
            master.Output(out)
        elif (targ == 3):
            mol = (p * v) / (0.08205 * t) 
            out = ("Answer: {.5f} mol").format(mol)
            master.Output(out)
        elif (targ == 4):
            temp = (p * v) / (n * 0.08205)
            out = ("Answer: {.5f} K").format(temp)
            master.Output(out)
```

Conversion Class

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import math
import turtle
from turtle import*

class Conversions: #Name of first unit respective to variable in methods. Name of second unit is returned
    """     Pressure Conversions     """
    def mmHg_ATM(master,a):
        return (a / 760)
    def mmHg_kPa(master,a):
        return (a / 7.50062)
        
    def kPa_mmHg(master,a):
        return ''
    def kPa_ATM(master,a):
        return (a / 101.325)
    def kPa_torr(master,a):
        return ''
        
    def ATM_torr(master,a):
        return ''
    def ATM_mmHg(master,a):
        return (a * 760)
    def ATM_kPa(master,a):
        return ''
    
    def torr_mmHg(master,a):
        return ''
    def torr_ATM(master,a):
        return (a / 760)
    def torr_kPa(master,a):
        return ''
    
    """     Volume Conversions     """
    def cm_L(master,a):
        return (a / 1000)
    
    def L_cm(master,a):
        return (a * 1000)
    
    """     Temperature Conversions     """
    def C_K(master,a):
        return (a + 273.15)
    def C_F(master,a):
        return ''
    
    def F_C(master,a):
        return (a / 101.325)
    def F_K(master,a):
        return (((a - 32) * 5 / 9) + 273.15)
    
    def K_C(master,a):
        return ''
    def K_F(master,a):
        return (a / 101.325)
```

Any help is extremely appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are having issues is that you have several `Tk` instances and your `IntVar`s are connected to a different instance than the radiobuttons. Since each `Tk` instance runs its own Tcl interpreter and they cannot communicate with each other, the variables cannot be linked with the radiobuttons' value.

Ideally you should have a single `Tk` instance and use the `Toplevel` class to get extra windows. You can also explicitly pass master when creating the variable: `var1 = tk.IntVar(master)`.

By the way, I advise you to read some tutorials about OOP and think about restructuring your whole code. Right now, you have defined classes but you are not really using them. The code inside could be as well outside the class, it would not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll look into it. I am pretty new to python so I was using this project as a chance to gather some insight into Tkinter, OOP, and eventually numpy and matplotlib